You cannot enable both Membership Signup and a Contribution Price Set on the same online contribution page?
Related to this one
Happened on a Contribution page, where we'd like to allow both Free Membership sign in AND additional contributions with some pre-defined amounts AND "the other amounts" allowed.
Have tried to add a Price Set but got the "You cannot enable both Membership Signup and a Contribution Price Set on the same online contribution page".
Not quite sure why would such kind of restriction be set. Any ideas of how to overcome this and have both memberships sign up and additional contributions on a same contribution form? Preferably without Webform involved (it's Drupal 7 and  CiviCRM 5.77.0)

Have you tried doing the contribution as part of the Member Price Set

@petednz-fuzion Good idea, I'm just not quite sure how to fit it into our set-up though. There are two separate parts: a contributions list with pre-defined amounts plus the "other amount" section AND a free ($0) membership offer. So visitors have a few choices:  - become a free member, no additional donations; - member + donate; - just donate, no membership.

Would a price set with a/ contribution radio field, b/ membership radio field, c/ donation 'other amount' ($1) work for you

@petednz-fuzion It would, perhaps, considering no other alternatives available. It's just, well, confusing - two system components and no "simple" way of co-existence within a single form.
